# How do I input variables in C++ class?

Tags: c++

I'm completely newbie and so frustrated when I tried to make my code with class ex. And I have this code

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class MyFunction {
 int a, b, x, y;
public:
 void setVar (int one, int two, int three, int four) {
    a = one;
    b = two;
    x = three;
    y = four;
 }
int result () {
    return (a-b)*(x-y);
 }
};

int main () {
 int one;
 int two;
 int three;
 int four;
 MyFunction equal;
 equal.setVar(one, two, three, four);
 cout << "Your number here "<< endl;
 cin >> one >> two >> three >> four;
 cout << "Your result is " << equal.result() << endl;

 return 0;
}
```

I want to make an output based on the variable (numbers) I input to the program. Everytime I run it, it'll be zero. Anyone can help me correcting what have I done wrong to the code?

Thanks.

Comment: `equal.setVar(one, two, three, four);` this stores the current values of one, two, three, four into the class. When these variables in main are updated with new values from cin, the members of MyFunction are not updated. You should put this line after you read the input.

Comment: `MyFunction` is not good name for a class...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You call `equal.setVar(one, two, three, four);` before getting the user input and filling the variables with proper values. Try this:

```
cout << "Your number here "<< endl;
cin >> one >> two >> three >> four;
equal.setVar(one, two, three, four);
cout << "Your result is " << equal.result() << endl;
```

And it is a good practice to give initial values to the variables you declare. Or they will contain values whatever the compiler sees to fit.

Answer (score 0):

You should call cin >> one >> two >> three >> four; before calling equal.setVar(one, two, three, four);